# Get service name from the path of its executable

Tags: windows, delphi

I have the path to an executable which is a running service application.

For example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Someapp\somesvc.exe`

I want to stop and start it, and for that I suppose I need to get the name of the service as it is outlined in [[this]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667588/how-can-i-restart-a-windows-service-application-written-in-delphi) answer.

I might get this by iterating trough all the registry entries of all the services at `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services`, and checking if the `ImagePath` registry key matches my executable path.

This solution should work, but it seems wrong to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use the service control manager API?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As I have linked in my question, I am going to use it, but it expects as a service name as an input, and not the path of the service, which is the main problem here.

Comment: The service control manager knows all the services, and all their details. Use that to extract the information you need. All I am suggesting is that you use the official API instead of hacking the registry. Of course, there could easily be multiple services registered with the same name.

Comment: Not all the services even HAVE their executable. Starting with Vista it was considered strain of system resources and effort was taken to convert those executables into SHARED services

Comment: @Arioch'The and for most services this behaviour has been reverted in Windows 10

Comment: @DavidHeffernan spot on, use the API's rather than enumerate registry

Comment: Let's back up a step: How did you even get into the position of having to restart a service without knowing its name? Maybe you can fix that and make the rest of the problem much easier.

Comment: Example: Firebird server might be registered under different names providing for co-existence of several versions. I think MS SQL registers services for different databases

Comment: @Arioch'The No, there is one `MSSQL` service per installed instance, not per database. The name is formatted like `MSSQL$INSTANCEID`. So, if you had an instance named `MyInstance` then the service name would be `MSSQL$MYINSTANCE` (assuming the Instance Name and Instance ID are the same).

Comment: On top of why you shouldn't look at the registry - What if your process is 32bit on a 64bit machine? If I recall, I think 64bit services are listed in the 64bit registry. As others have said, Windows has an API for the specific task, and that's what you should use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`EnumServicesStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682637.aspx) or [`EnumServicesStatusEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682640.aspx) to enumerate installed services.  That will give you the name of each service, but not its `ImagePath`.  To retrieve that, you can open each service using [`OpenService(SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330.aspx) and then get its `ImagePath` using [`QueryServiceConfig()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684932.aspx).

Comment: This was the correct solution, thank you. I needed a lot of digging around though, most of the tutorials online about these functions do not work properly with new delphi versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can query to WMI for services that `PathName` is like your path.

**NOTE**: Some path include params. You can't use equal (use Like).

You can use some code like this to query WMI:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//     This code was generated by the Wmi Delphi Code Creator (WDCC) Version 1.9.9.350
//     http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/
//     Blog http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/
//     Author Rodrigo Ruz V. (RRUZ) Copyright (C) 2011-2015 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//
//     LIABILITY DISCLAIMER
//     THIS GENERATED CODE IS DISTRIBUTED "AS IS". NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND IS EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED.
//     YOU USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK. THE AUTHOR NOT WILL BE LIABLE FOR DATA LOSS,
//     DAMAGES AND LOSS OF PROFITS OR ANY OTHER KIND OF LOSS WHILE USING OR MISUSING THIS CODE.
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
program GetWMI_Info;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;



// La clase Win32_Service representa un servicio en un sistema Win32. Un 
// aplicación de servicio cumple las reglas de la interfaz del Administrador de 
// control de servicios (SCM, Service Control Manager) y un usuario la puede 
// iniciar automáticamente al arrancar el sistema a través del programa Servicios 
// del Panel de control o mediante una aplicación que utilice las funciones de 
// servicio de la API de Win32. Los servicios se pueden ejecutar aunque ningún 
// usuario haya iniciado sesión en el sistema.

procedure  GetWin32_ServiceInfo(sPath:String);
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE PathName like "%' + sPath + '%"','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('Caption        %s',[String(FWbemObject.Caption)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('DisplayName    %s',[String(FWbemObject.DisplayName)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('Name           %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('PathName       %s',[String(FWbemObject.PathName)]));// String

    Writeln('');
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_ServiceInfo(ExtractFileName('c:\windows\system\locator.exe'));
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode])); 
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;      
end.
```

If you need more properties, add to precedure.

For query with: `'c:\windows\system\locator.exe'`, you obtain:

[image]

For query with: `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Updater\Updater.exe'`, you obtain:

[image]

For **Start** and **Stop** the service, tou need the `property Name`.

Comment: I downvoted this because WMI is "evil" IMO, it is slow and with lot's of overhead. The SCM API can be used to iterate services and compare paths... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Remko.  
That is a personal opinion.
For a problem there may be several valid solutions. What for you is bad, for another person can be good.
I do not understand a negative vote because the solution is not the one you propose or the one you like.

Comment: It's a really poor solution. WMI is the wrong tool for the job. My downvote too.

Comment: Because WMI is a solution that is really meant for scripting and is horribly slow thus adding unnecessary delays to an application. If WMI was the only way, fine, but there is well documented api that has been in Windows since the early days and is easily accessible in Delphi.

Comment: Even if this were an ideal solution, this code has no error checking. What if WMI isn't running (which I've seen before)? What if the user does not have sufficient privileges? What if the requested service does not exist? Even further - what if there is more than one service spawned from the same executable? Yes, that is possible.

Comment: This did not work for me, I got an error telling me something about an incorrect query.

Comment: @Sevron. I have compiled this code with Delphi XE7 and Delphi 10 Seatle, and compile and run ok. What version are you using?

Comment: @Jerry Dodge. It is true that the code lacks important parts.
The intention was not to generate a complete and terminated code, but an approximation to be able to develop from it.

Comment: @GermánEstévez-Neftalí- The code compiled fine, the error is something Windows related I guess. I'm using windows 10 x64, what OS are you using?

Comment: @Sevron. I'm Using Windows 8.1 64bits.