# API help to get PathName of service run on windows by C

Tags: c, windows, service, wmic

I need to get the system services executables system paths using C. I have found some functions in `MSDN` such as: `GetService`, `GetServiceDisplayName`,etc. However they do not return path to the service executable.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this post helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884963/what-directory-does-a-windows-service-run-in

Comment: Here in accepted answer there is a good description of how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264625/get-service-name-from-the-path-of-its-executable